# java: how do i print all of the values in an int array

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to print the entire array `sPack[]`. I take in up to 500 values into `sPack` then I sort in ascending order. My median value is off so I would like to print what my sort method is doing so I can see if it is an issue with my median method or my sort method.

```
int [] sPack = new int [500];
int i = 0;
String input = br.readLine();
while(input!=null && i<500 && input.length()!=0)//(!input.isEmpty()&& i<500)//
{
  sPack [i] = Integer.parseInt (input);
  i++;
  input = br.readLine();
}
sort(sPack, i);
double Var = calcVariance(sPack,i);
System.out.println (sPack); //this is where i need help***************<==
```

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sPack));`

Comment: This is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array

Answer (score 2):

Use `java.util.Arrays.toString()` this is the easiest and convinient method to print all elements of an array.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sPack));
```

Or you can choose the hard way to traverse through the array and print each element.

```
for(int i =0; i < sPack.length; i++){
    System.out.println(sPack[i]);
}
```

Great, if you are using Java 8

```
Stream.of(strArray).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for (int pack : sPack) {
    System.out.println(pack);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answers provided here, you can also do it the following way:

`Arrays.stream(sPack).forEach(System.out::println);`